# How to add an overlay to video programatically

Tags: video, overlay

How can I add a dynamic image overlay to a video programatically? I want the image to move each frame to a specified location on the video. I'm looking for any tools or libraries that would enable me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

That's remarkably simple to do by using Cloudinary's [image overlay feature](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/video_manipulation_and_delivery#adding_image_overlays) whereby you can manipulate both the frame placement and the image itself dynamically via the URL.